# Insert object in Elements - Jsoup Java

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to insert some Strings in an Elements Jsoup object. Here is what I have done so far:

```
Elements hrefs = null;
Elements div = null;
Elements atag = null;

div = doc.select("div#id1");
atag = div.select("a.class1");

for (Element ahref : atag){

         String wholeURL = "<a href='http://www.example.com" + ahref.attr("href")+ "'>more</a>";
         Document docu = Jsoup.parse(wholeURL, "", Parser.xmlParser());
         hrefs.add(docu); // <-- here I get NullPointerException

}
```

I tried to use Elements hrefs.add() but I get nullPointerException. Any thoughts?

Comment: check what `atag` contains

Comment: atag contains the <a href=" .... </a> . atag is not my problem. My problem is how to insert the Document docu inside hrefs Elements.

Comment: How does your stacktrace looks like? Where exactly is that `null`? If it is `hrefs` then case is simple because when you call `hrefs.add(docu);` you are invoking `null.add(..)` but `null` doesn't have `add` method.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. How I initiate the hrefs then?

Comment: Ok I found it, thanks for the help.